# OS reads only 1600GB of my 4TB hard drive

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, gpt

I'm trying to format a 4 TB hard drive as a single partition. I am running Windows 2008 Server R2 Standard, Service Pack 1. I have already tried converting my disk to GPT, successfully, but that only increments the number read by the OS by something like 20 GB. It's something like 1600 GB MBR and 1620 GB after converting it to GPT. How do I get the OS to recognize all 4 TB as a single partition?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a hardware compatibility problem.  What size does your BIOs report for the drive? Please include hardware information (motherboard, BIOS revision,  HDD controller make/model, etc.)  Has the drive been tested elsewhere to confirm it's not defective?

Comment: I agree with @techie007.  I know my motherboard requires a bios update and a special driver in order to work with drives 3TB or larger.  I suggest checking your mobo manufacturer's website for updates.

Comment: I believe that you're [limited to 2 TB volumes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773268%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) in 2008 for boot volumes if you're not booting EFI.

Comment: @ernie the 2TB limit is for MBR disks, and the user says they've formatted it GPT.  GPT (under Windows 2008 R2) can theoretically handle up to 18 exabytes of data, but 'the Windows file systems currently are limited to 256 terabytes each'. [Windows and GPT FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463525.aspx)

Comment: @techie007 from my understanding, if it's the boot volume, even with GPT format, you're still [limited to 2TB unless you're booting EFI](http://carltonbale.com/how-to-break-the-2tb-2-terabyte-file-system-limit/)

Comment: @techie007 the bios is showing the full 4 TB capacity, it's just the OS which fails to do the same. Will I have to reinstall Windows using UEFI mode, and repartition all the drives? The most commonly available solution suggests that I should boot from a GPT drive, and that I should install Windows using UEFI. Any further comments on this?

Comment: @AnupamMehendaley is this drive the boot drive or just a secondary storage drive?

Comment: @ernie it is not the boot drive, but I want to assign C: to it. I am now trying a Windows reinstall from a UEFI device.

Answer (score 2):

This type of problem has two common sources:

- An external enclosure that's limited to 2TiB. If you've placed a 4TB disk in an external enclosure (especially an older one), I'd investigate this option first. Unfortunately, the only solution I've ever heard of working is switching to another enclosure (moving the disk to an internal connector counts as "another enclosure").
- A disk driver that uses a 32-bit pointer somewhere that it should not. Upgrading your disk driver software can often work around this problem, although if your manufacturer has stopped providing updates, you may be out of luck. This problem is most common with 32-bit versions of Windows, but I've seen one or two reports of it even with 64-bit versions of Windows, too. Switching to another OS is another possible (albeit radical) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Computer (right mouse button) -> Manage -> Disk Managment

[image]

Let guess your first Partition is C: and it's 1600GB ? 
Then another amount of memory is not formated and the File System is not set ? 
Enter Disk Managment and Check

I never used MS Server so Im not pretty sure, but im glad to help if i can :)

Comment: Yes, the partitions are indeed sized as you guessed.